# Rename Multiple files in a Folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to rename a multiple excel files. Where code will load a range from `Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")` and rename the all workbooks.

[image]

No error is appearing while running the code but still it does not work.

Your help will be highly appreciated

```
Sub MyFiles()

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Dim objFileSystem As Object
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim OriginalFile, RenamedFile As String
    Dim Myrng As Range

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    Set Myrng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")
    
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'Looping through each .xlsx file in the source folder
     For Each OriginalFile In objFileSystem.getfolder(sItem).Files
    
    'Check if selected file is an excel file
     If InStr(OriginalFile, ".xlsx") Then
     
     MyFileLocation = objFileSystem.GetParentFolderName(OriginalFile)
     
     RenamedFile = MyFileLocation & "\" & MyPrefix & Replace(Dir(OriginalFile), ".xlsx", "") & ".xlsx"
     
     'Rename original file
     Name OriginalFile As RenamedFile
     End If
     Next OriginalFile
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you removing xlsx and then adding?  OriginalFile will be of `File` type, so will have `.name` to use declare it as a File and you will see its intellisense also load Scripting.Runtime library as a reference.

Comment: To make sure that its format could not change. `OriginalFile will be of File type, so will have .name to use declare it as a File and you will see its intellisense` i don't understadn this line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not defining MyPrefix. So effectively, you're adding nothing to the front of the filename, and replace xlsx with xlsx...

I used Early Binding with the following rewrite of your code - let me know how it goes:

```
Sub MyFiles()

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim NewFilenames As Variant, counter As Long

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

    NewFilenames = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:A20").Value)
    
    Dim objFileSystem As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder, OriginalFile As Scripting.File
    Set objFileSystem = New FileSystemObject 'CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFileSystem.GetFolder(sItem)
    
    'Looping through each .xlsx file in the source folder
     For Each OriginalFile In objFolder.Files
        'Check if selected file is an excel file
        If OriginalFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" Then
            counter = counter + 1
            OriginalFile.Name = NewFilenames(counter) & ".xlsx"
        End If
    Next OriginalFile
    
    Set fldr = Nothing
    Set OriginalFile = Nothing
    Set objFileSystem = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Early Binding was helpful because of the Intellisense functionality - which I see was first suggested by Nathan_sav. To get Intellisense, click on Tools -> References -> select the 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' checkbox. Then it was just a matter of adding the prefix (now stored in a variant-type variable) to the front of the file's NAME property.

Comment: Thank you but it does not remove the previous file name. It just concatenate the previous and new name. https://ibb.co/k207YZ9

Comment: Ok, but that's what your code did (MyPrefix & Replace(Dir(OriginalFile), ".xlsx", "") - so I assumed that's all you wanted and... now that I think about it... that's what 'prefix' means... it concatenates something to the front of something else... I think I must have misread something.

Comment: Yes please just one update is required where Old file name will be removed and new will be replaced.

Comment: Ok - have edited the code above, replaceing PrefixList with a NewFilenames variable. Please let me know if it works as required. Make sure you test it properly on dummy files/data before using it on real files, and please make sure you keep backups.

Comment: Hi - did this end up helping?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.Name` of the `File` object. The section of your code that loops over files should use logic like this:

```
Dim f as Scripting.File
Dim OldFileName as String
Dim NewFileName as String
Dim extn as String
For Each f in objFileSystem.GetFolder(sItem).Files
    OldFileName = f.Name
    extn = objFileSystem.GetExtension(OldFileName)
    If extn = "xlsx" Then
        NewFileName = "" ' Calculate new file name --- wasn't clear to me how you wanted to do this
        f.Name = NewFileName
    End If
Next f
```

Comment: `NewFileName= WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:A20").Value)` It should take the name from given range.